# Trying to get non-object cakephp 3.5

Tags: cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.4

I'm new in cakephp 3.5. I just recently read the same question and I use those solutions. The problem is I tried the solution answered in the past question but it didn't display the needed attributes.

view.ctp (client_transaction)

```
<div class="related">
    <?php if (!empty($clientTransaction->service_detail)): ?>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col"><?= __('Service Detail ID') ?></th>
            <th scope="col"><?= __('Barber') ?></th>
            <th scope="col"><?= __('Service') ?></th>
            <th scope="col"><?= __('Price') ?></th>
            <th scope="col" class="actions"><?= __('Actions') ?></th>
        </tr>
        <!--pre>
        <?php print_r($clientTransaction->service_detail); ?>
      </pre-->

        <?php foreach ($clientTransaction->service_detail as $serviceDetail): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $this->Number->format($serviceDetail->id) ?></td>
            <!-- the first solution-->
            <td><?= h($serviceDetail->users->first_name)?></td>
            <!-- the second solution-->
            <td><?= h($serviceDetail->service->name) ?></td>
            <td><?= h($serviceDetail->service->price) ?></td>
            <td class="actions">
                <?= $this->Form->postLink(__('Cancel'), ['controller' => 'ServiceDetail','action' => 'delete', $serviceDetail->id], ['confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to cancel # {0}?', $serviceDetail->id)]) ?>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

[The screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yp901.png)

I'm just asking for help. I'm also trying to figure it out. Thank you!

P.S: I just edited the code and the screenshot so that you'll get understand of the problem. thanks!

Comment: If you do `debug($serviceDetail);`, what output do you get? Without knowing what your data looks like, we can't even guess what the solution would be.

Comment: it will return null

Comment: It's clearly not actually null, because you're getting IDs from it in the table. Maybe you put the debug before the `foreach` instead of inside, where it would be set?

Comment: It would be a syntax error. I'm thinking about fetching all the variables from service details. I need to join with the service detail in able to get it because it is on a client transaction. So I'm still figuring out how to fetch the needed the data

Comment: It may be that you already have the required data, but since you won't show us what the data looks like, it's quite hard to say.

Comment: But do you know how to merge two models in a index form? May be it would be the solution for showing the required data?

Comment: If you would show us the structure of your data, for example by putting `debug($serviceDetail);` inside your foreach loop, or `debug($clientTransaction);` outside of it as @Mr.D requested, then we could help more. But as long as you insist on keeping your data a mystery, it's really hard.

Comment: I just edited the question, the code and the screenshot

Comment: @GregSchmidt i've try the debug($serviceDetail); inside the for loop. the error is: Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context

Comment: You get that error with the code exactly as it is shown right now? (You said `debug()`, but the code is `print_r`, is why I ask.) Maybe just try `<?php debug($clientTransaction); ?>` at the very top of what you've shown?

Comment: Okay, can I post the screenshot here about the result of print_r?

Comment: Or can we have a chat @GregSchmidt?

Comment: Screen shot isn't ideal, but better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach ($clientTransaction->service_detail as $serviceDetail): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $this->Number->format($serviceDetail->id) ?></td>
        <!-- the first solution-->
        <td><?= $serviceDetail->user!==null ? h($serviceDetail->user->first_name) : ''?></td>
        <!-- the second solution-->
        <td><?= h($serviceDetail['service']['name']) ?></td>
        <td><?= h($serviceDetail['service']['price']) ?></td>
        <td class="actions">
          <!--  <?= $this->Html->link(__('View'), ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'view', $user->id]) ?>
            <?= $this->Html->link(__('Edit'), ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'edit', $user->id]) ?> -->
            <?= $this->Form->postLink(__('Cancel'), ['action' => 'delete', $serviceDetail->id], ['confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to cancel # {0}?', $serviceDetail->id)]) ?>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

That should be - remember to remove your IF: (I hope this help)

```
<?php foreach ($clientTransactions as $serviceDetails): ?>
    <?php foreach ($serviceDetails->service_detail as $serviceDetail): ?>
           //Code to excute here
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

not:

```
<?php foreach ($clientTransaction->service_detail as $serviceDetail): ?>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. That is already given by bake cakephp. The barber, service name and price shows their primary key. I want to show the name of the users, service name and price instead of id